# How to get/delete multiple rows in SQLITE table in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

My table in SQLITE is in the following format.

```
id   name      date      height
 1    tt     12-2-15       120
 2    ss     15-3-15       110
 3    tt     14-5-15       120
 ....
 10   tt     19-6-15       130
```

(1)I like to get all rows under name tt in one instruction, then put into two dimensional array. How can i implement it?

(2)How to delete all rows under name tt in one instruction?

My code is in iOS. I couldn't find solution easily.

EDIT:
Just to share what I implement.

```
    NSString *databasePath;
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    //Database
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"RECORDS.db"]];
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath,& RECORDS) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        retval = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id, nameid, date, height FROM RECORD WHERE nameid=\"%@\"", currentNameID];
        const char *query_stmt = [query UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(RECORDS, query_stmt, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                char *date = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
                int height = (int) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
                NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:date];
                HeightInfo *info = [[HeightInfo alloc] initWithInfos:name withheight:(int)height];
                [retval addObject:info];

            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(RECORDS);
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: There are many topics covering SQLite here.  If none of them helps you, then what else could help you?

Comment: Sorry bro. I just couldn't find info easily. Now I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need help with the SQL or the ios framework?
The SQL is pretty straightforward;

```
select id, name, date, height from mytablename where name = "tt";

delete from mytablename where name == "tt";
```

Practice the commands on the command line so you see how they work.

For processing your data look at the great examples by Ray Wenderlich;

http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app

Comment: Thanks I implemented as you suggested. I couldn't find the info easily. Thanks